# Python. How to convert MOBI file to a text (or EPUB file)

Tags: python, epub, ebooklib

I have problems with converting MOBI file to a text in Python.

I found this library - https://github.com/iscc/mobi that should convert MOBI to EPUB and then I found ebooklib library that is working very well with converting EPUB files to text.

The thing is that only ebooklib seems to be working properly. If I give it native EPUB file everything is working correctly. But If I try to pass to it filepath from mobi library then I receive bunch of errors that doesn't make much sense.

And I don't know what exactly is causing this. Maybe my MOBI files are encrypted somehow? (they are original books from Humble Bundle that I bought several months ago). But mobi library is not throwing any error about this.

Or maybe I cannot just pass filepath generated by mobi library as it is? Maybe I should somehow save this file, move it to some other folder and only then it will be "readable" by ebooklib?

My code looks like this:

```
import mobi

import ebooklib
from ebooklib import epub

tempdir, filepath = mobi.extract("book.mobi")

# This throws error:
book = epub.read_epub(filepath)

# Native, normal epub file is working ok:
book = epub.read_epub("book.epub")
```

Error isn't telling much in my opinion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ebooklib/utils.py", line 35, in parse_string
tree = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(s.encode('utf-8')))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it as html  file

```
pip install mobi
```

than

```
import mobi
filepath="./example.mobi"
folder="./"

!mobiunpack -r   filepath folder
```

List of all options available [here](https://pypi.org/project/mobi/)

Or here I propose another method:

```
pip install mobi
pip install html2text

import mobi
import html2text

filename="test.mobi"
tempdir, filepath = mobi.extract(filename)
file = open(filepath, "r")
content=file.read()
print(html2text.html2text(content))
```

Comment: But this code isn't working. Even If I change it to python conde, delete ';', fix the for loop (it isn't using 'record' anywhere?) then it is showing me that 'mobi' doesn't have 'Mobi'. And later it is showing me error on 'book.parse()' - `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'parse'`

Comment: Yes checked this error due to old python version , I just changed the code for Python3

Comment: I'm sorry, if I could have one more question. I am wondering if it is possible to loop over pages in this setup? Because as far as I checked it looks like after `extract` we basically have "one" string of text without information about pages?

Comment: I think best way is to check the list of full options of the mobiunpack command otherwise need a way to iterate over them.